# how to make my app as calendar data source in windows phone?

Tags: c#, calendar, windows-phone-8, accounts

I am creating an app which has its own calender. So any event added to that calendar should also be shown in the original calendar in windows phone 8. This is what happens if we add facebook to my phone. Facebook becomes one of the data source of the calendar. I want my app to also become a source. How to do it ?

Any other trick that might solve my problem here ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the SaveAppointmentTask as described here:

[SaveAppointmentTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207038%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Note that Windows Phone allows limited interaction with the Calendar app.  You can insert new appointments, but are not allowed to modify or delete existing ones.

Comment: SaveAppointmentTask will add entry into the default datasource, in this case may be outlook account or something that the phone is synced to. I need to create a separate account for my entries so that I have full control over my entries and also it will be easy for me to filter out all the events and to get entries done from my app only. Any idea how to create an account?

Comment: I think the calendar uses Exchange ActiveSync to get data from different sources.  I am not familiar with what your server would need to do to implement this.